# How do I calculate a payroll directly from an attendance records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**MySQL Database Table:** (Name: Attendance)

```
RecID | EmployeeID | Date     | Name | WorkedHours | Absence | OverTime
------+------------+----------+------+-------------+---------+---------
434   | 7          | 19/11/16 | Jack | 8           |         | 1
435   | 7          | 20/11/16 | Jack | 8           |         | 0
436   | 7          | 21/11/16 | Jack | 8           |         | 0
437   | 8          | 19/11/16 | Nik  | 8           |         | 1
438   | 8          | 20/11/16 | Nik  | 0           |    1    | 0
439   | 8          | 21/11/16 | Nik  | 8           |         | 1
```

I would like to show the following **payroll report** using PHP:

```
 EmployeeID | Month | Name | WorkedDays| Deductions| Overtime | Net Pay
 -----------+-------+------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------
 7          | 11/16 | Jack | 3         |           |          | 1
 8          | 11/16 | Nik  | 2         |           |          | 0
```

What I tried so far was the following using **SQL**:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, 
        COUNT(*) AS WorkedDays, 
        (COUNT(*) * $DailyWage) AS 'Net Pay'
        FROM `Attendance` 
        GROUP BY EmployeeID;
```

Is there a way I can do that through a **PHP** loop? Something like

```
$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Attendance GROUP BY EmployeeID");
while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){
        $WorkedDays++;
        echo "WorkedDays: " . $WorkedDays;
        // Doesn't make sense but just giving example.
    }
```

Please let me know if you need any details. Thank you.

Comment: Probably - but what's wrong with the SQL approach?

Comment: SQL probably would run much faster.

Comment: Because I have to use JOIN in the query and it's going to complicate things

Comment: Maybe after you learn more JOIN wont be so complicated.

Comment: `PHP loop without SQL? ` how will you remove the SQL if the data is on DB?

Comment: What I mean is that I want to retrieve the data from the database and then calculate it using PHP. I don't want to remove the SQL.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using mysql_query by the way.  It's deprecated in PHP 5 due to not having been maintained for years, and it's completely missing in PHP 7.  You should use some other SQL API like mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I know, I will change it later. Thanks.